# How to add an animation on Ionic 5 once click on a button?

Tags: css, ionic5

My code is the following, but it doesn't work, what i want is to activate the effect once button clicked.
//TS

```
@ViewChild('icono', { read: ElementRef })icono: ElementRef;

execEffect() {
    let x = this.icono
    x.nativeElement.classList.add('bounce')
}
```

//HTML

```
<img #icono src="../../assets/something.png" style="width:60px;" (click)="execEffect()"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use Renderer 2...

I made and example four you...

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bsqd5d

Comment: Thank you! at the end i put another transitions